# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'Footerdit-content-page-settings' not found or invalid function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Me aparece ese error en el apartado donde debería aparecer el formulario, y no entiendo cual es el problema, recién comienzo con el tema de plugins y sigo tutoriales de Youtube y blogs, es un código que ya había publicado pero ahora lo estoy mejorando(aclaro que el plugin será gratuito y visible en Github publicamente)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Footerdit
Plugin URI: diweb.website
Description: Editing the footer text
Version: 1.0
Author: Liam Redes
Author URI: diweb.website
License: GPLv2
*/

function plugin_menu()
{
  add_menu_page('Footerdit', 'Footerdit', 'administrator', 'Footerdit_content_settings', 'Footerdit_content_page_settings', 'dashicons-admin-generic');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_menu');

function page_settings()
{?>

<div class="wrap">
  <h2>Footerdit</h2>
  <form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php
      settings_fields('settings_group');
      do_settings_sections('settings_group');
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="Footerdit" id="fClass" placeholder="Put the class of your footer" value="<?php echo get_option('Footer-value'); ?>">
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
  </form>
</div>
<?php }
  function settings()
  {
    register_setting('settings_group', 'Footer-value', 'intval');
  }
  add_action('admin_init', 'settings');
 ?>
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: el quinto parámetro que espera `add_menu_page()` es una función callable, como se puede ver en la [documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/). En tu código ese parámetro es `Footerdit-content-page-settings` y el mensaje de error te está diciendo que NO existe una función llamada `Footerdit-content-page-settings`. ¿Dónde has declarado esa función?

Comment: Ooooh ahora entiendo esa función, no lo tenía tan claro por que no lo explicaban casi nada a los códigos, muchas gracias, voy  a agregar un respuesta de mi parte, gracias Cedano, siempre me ayudas en esto, te lo agradezco mucho, sin vos no podría avanzar en este nuevo aprendizaje, muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 2):

Como dijo Cedano en los comentarios, add_menu_page() es una función callable, entonces, como yo tenía un parametro llamado 'Footerdit-content-page-settings' lo que hice fue cambiar en donde tengo

```
function page_settings()
{?>
```

Por esto:

```
function Footerdit_content_page_settings()
{?>
```

Y todo se arregló, gracias a Cedano